# How does an aframe entity defaults to the schema ones if no data is passed on

Tags: schema, entity, aframe

I'm having some difficulties in understanding how in aFrame an entity works with schema and data together. Forgive me, I'm a bit new in the library and maybe I'm missing something. Thanks.

Consider the following:

```
// register the aframe component (Button.js):

import { registerComponent, THREE } from 'aframe'

const button = registerComponent('button', {
  schema: {
    width: { type: 'number', default: 0.6 },
    height: { type: 'number', default: 0.40 },
    color: { type: 'string', default: 'orange' },
  },
  init: function() {
    const schema = this.schema // Schema property values.
    const data = this.data // Component property values.
    const el = this.el // Reference to the component's entity.

    // Create geometry.
    this.geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(data.width || schema.width.default, data.height || schema.height.default, data.depth || schema.depth.default)

    // Create material.
    this.material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: data.color || schema.color.default })

    // Create mesh.
    this.mesh  = new THREE.Mesh(this.geometry, this.material)

    // Set mesh on entity.
    el.setObject3D('mesh', this.mesh)
  }
})

export default button

// add the entity in the app (App.js)
import button from './Button'

<a-entity button="width: 0.4; height: 0.4: color: 'green'" position="0 0 0"></a-entity>
```

Now with the example above I would expect that my component will use data instead of schema defaults. And if I would instead just do:

```
<a-entity button position="0 0 0"></a-entity>
```

It would use the schema default ones.
Is this how it should be done?
I've been seeing a lot of examples where people just use data.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `schema` isn't intended to be used directly. From the [docs](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/introduction/writing-a-component.html#defining-properties-with-the-schema):

> The schema defines the **properties** of its component. (...)
> The component’s **property** type values are available through **this.data**

The idea goes like this:

- You define the properties (with defaults) in the schema

  ```
  schema {
    prop: {default: "default value"}
  },
  ```
- You access the values with `this.data[prop_name]`:

  ```
  init: function() {
    console.log("prop value at init:", this.data.prop)
  },
  ```
- You can monitor the property updates (like via `setAttribute("propname", "newValue")` within the `update` handler:

  ```
  update: function(oldData) {
       console.log("prop changed from", oldData.prop, "to", this.data.prop)
  },
  ```

---

In a setup like this:

```
<!-- this.data.prop will contain the default values -->
<a-entity foo></a-entity>

<!-- this.data.prop will contain the new value -->
<a-entity foo="prop: value></a-entity>
```

Comment: Hi Piotr. Totally makes sense. Thanks for the clarification. 
For some reason at a certain point in time I had to do something like:
`const elWidth = data.width || schema.default.width` within the `init()`. It didn't felt right, but now I can't remember why.

For now I left just data as you mentioned and indeed if passed on or not I still get the default or the one passed on through the component. Thank you.

Comment: @marco.cardoso glad i could help!